# wpf: checking how many components are inside of a Span?

Tags: wpf, search, html, inlines

I have WPF Span that is used as a source to a TextBlock. I am doing some tests and it would be very helpful to know in code how many of which type of component is inside of the Span.

For example, at one point I insert a new Bold() into the span's inlines. How would I check that there is exactly one Bold component contained inside of the span?

I'm not too sure how to search Span.Inlines to retrieve this number.

Comment: did you try visualtreehelper? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.visualtreehelper.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can iterate over the `Inlines` property of the `Span` :

```
int count = 0;
foreach(Inline inline in span.Inlines)
{
    if (inline is Bold) count++;
}
```